# Нужен совет по работе с аудио и видео

Tags: аудио, видео

Есть компьютер(ноутбук), 2 веб камеры, и микрофон(может быть и не будет). И скажем толстый клиент, где будет кнопка начать запись, когда нажимаем 2 камеры начинают снимать, а когда нажимаем стоп 2 видео сохранится в папке локальном, и их нужно объединить в одно. В результате получим одно видео.

Теперь вопросы:
1. На каком языке все это реализовать?
2. Какие библиотеки лучше использовать в работе с видео?

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с веб камерами пользуйте openCV. Она есть на разных языках ( я пользовал для захвата с вебки и поиска лиц на видео)